# EJS, Express, Mongoose - EJS not picking the data from async function in route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

```
//App.js Code: 
app.get("/secrets", async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const usersWithSecrets = await User.find({"secret": {$ne: null}});
        console.log("Users with secrets:", usersWithSecrets);

        res.render("secrets", { usersWithSecrets: usersWithSecrets || [] });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while finding users:", error);
        res.render("secrets", { usersWithSecrets: [] });
    }
});
```

```
//EJS Code: 

    <% if (usersWithSecrets && usersWithSecrets.length > 0) { %>
      <% usersWithSecrets.forEach(function(user) { %>
        <p class="secret-text"><%= user.secret %></p>
      <% }); %>
    <% } else { %>
      <p>No secrets found.</p>
    <% } %>
```

I keep getting a reference error on usersWithSecrets.
I do have access to the database and can access the secret.

I think the problem has to do with the async await as in a normal function mongoose does not accept a callback anymore.

And EJS executes before the async is complete. I also tried with an if statement in the EJS file to only render if the usersWithSecrets has a length greater than 0 but still get the error.

> //ERROR:
> - Authentication & Security\Secrets - Starting
> Code\views\secrets.ejs:8
> 6|     You've Discovered My Secret!
> 7|
> >> 8|     <% if (usersWithSecrets && usersWithSecrets.length > 0) { %>
> 9|       <% usersWithSecrets.forEach(function(user) { %>
> 10|         <%= user.secret %>
>
> 11|       <% }); %>
>
> ```
> usersWithSecrets is not defined
> at eval
> ```

Comment: When you `console.log("Users with secrets:", usersWithSecrets)` what does it output in the console? Are there documents or is it an empty array `[]`?

Comment: it does give me the detailed document with id, secrets etc. The problem comes when I redirect to the secrets page and the ejs does not pick the usersWithSecrets.

Comment: Can you post the reference error? The full error, not changed in any way. Edit the question and post in there, not in the comments please. Thank you.

Comment: It is saying `usersWithSecrets` is not defined so it hasn't been sent to that ejs template file. Do you have a typo in your actual code on your machine? Are you sure `app.get("/secrets"` is the request that is responding and not some other route handler is picking up the request?

Answer (score 0):

I had a submit button that was redirecting to the *'secrets'* page on a post.

I had used a ***res.render("secrets")*** instead of ***res.redirect("/secrets).***
Once I changed that, the EJS picked it up just fine.